# Mat-menu doesn't change position automatically when the is no enough space below

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a way to automatically change position of mat-menu when it placed at the bottom of a page and user dynamically hides/shows content after mat-menu trigger.

The screenshots below show what I have now:

[mat-menu opened and content is not hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS4xi.png)

After click on Hide it hides text that is below it

[mat-menu opened and content is hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRV5B.png)

But it doesn't automatically moves menu higher after text was hidden. Only after re-opening this menu it displays correctly.

The example on the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9du61?file=src/app/menu-overview-example.html

P.S.: I stop propagation for the mat-menu items click therefore the menu is not closing after click on some menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc. Positioning takes place before display. There is no way to post-position based on API. At this point, I suggest closing the menu after click and then reopening it from program code.

Answer (score 0):

Anna, the simplest way to fix problem is predefine starting position of the menu. For instance, you can define position Y like "above". Hiding text no longer breaks the page.
Please, look at the [documantation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#customizing-menu-position)

```js
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); hidden = true">
    Hide
  </button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); hidden = false">
    Show
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Yes it might help but in my case necessary to show menu below the trigger button